# Distance between opposite vertices of 2 joint (by base) tetrahedrons

Tags: geometry

I have two tetrahedrons joint by base (let's call it **ABC** triangle):

1. tetrahedron **ABCD**
2. tetrahedron **ABCE**

I know lengths (read as *distances*) of all edges. Is there any reasonably simple way to find length (distance) of **DE**?

Also, if you know how to find height of the tetrahedron by the **lengths** of edges, please comment or add answer - this I feel would be 90% of the solution.

PS: those figures are general and are not of special case.

[Image just to clarify how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOoLS.png)

Any input would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "values" of edges, do you have coordinates of vertices?

Comment: They know the lengths of the edges but not necessarily the vertices, is my interpretation.

Comment: @TonyS.F. exactly. I have only the length. Sorry for confusion. Will fix this in question.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be solved using the formulas for the $n$-dimensional volume of an $n$-dimensional simplex. It can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant).
For five points $P_0,\ldots,P_4$ in 4-dimensional space and their mutual distances $d_{ij}=\overline{P_iP_j}$, $i\neq j$ the 4-dimensional volume or content $C$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
C^2 & = -\frac{1}{(4!)^2 2^4} 
\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & d_{01}^2 & d_{02}^2 & d_{03}^2 & d_{04}^2 & 1 \\
d_{01}^2 & 0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2 & 1 \\
d_{02}^2 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2 & 1 \\
d_{03}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0  &d_{34}^2 & 1 \\
d_{04}^2 & d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2& 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
In the question, we have five points. We rename them $P_1=A$, $P_2=B$, $P_3=C$, $P_4=D$ and finally $P_0=E$. The key obervation is that they are contained in a 3-dimensional subspace if and only if $C=0$ (and $P_1$,..,$P_4$ and $P_0$,$P_2$,$P_3$,$P_4$, respectively, form non-degenerate tetrahedra).
This gives an equation for $x=d_{01}^2$:
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & x & d_{02}^2 & d_{03}^2 & d_{04}^2 & 1 \\
x & 0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2 & 1 \\
d_{02}^2 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2 & 1 \\
d_{03}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0  &d_{34}^2 & 1 \\
d_{04}^2 & d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2& 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=0.
\end{align}$$
Using [Laplace's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org%7B91c14fbe-8ad9-421e-a25d-046da1a11514%7D/wiki/Determinant#Laplace%27s_expansion_and_the_adjugate_matrix), it can be seen that this is a quadratic equation for $x$. The larger solution is $x_1=\overline{DE}^2$, the smaller solution is $x_2=\overline{DE'}^2$, where $E'$ is the symmetric to $E$ with respect to the plane containing $A,B,C$. Observe that $\overline{AE'}=\overline{AE}$, $\overline{BE'}=\overline{BE}$ and $\overline{CE'}=\overline{CE}$.

The coefficient $M$ of $x^2$ in this equation actually is the negative of a subdeterminant:
$$M=-
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2 & 1 \\
 d_{23}^2 & 0  &d_{34}^2 & 1 \\
 d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2& 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
Again by the determinant formula, this is $M=16A^2$, where $A$ is the area of the triangle $P_2P_3P_4$.

The heights mentioned in the question can also be expressed using determinants.
The volume $V$ of the tetrahedron $P_1P_2P_3P_4$ is given by
$$V^2=\frac1{3!^2 2^3}
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2 & 1 \\
 d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2 & 1 \\
 d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0  &d_{34}^2 & 1 \\
 d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2& 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
One  height of this tetrahedron, i.e. the distance $h$ of $P_1$ from $P_2P_3P_4$ is
then obtained from the formula
$$V=\frac13 Ah$$
where $A$ is the area of the triangle $P_2P_3P_4$ expressed above.

Answer (score 0):

We can construct a tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0),(1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)$

The center face opposite the vertex at the origin is $(\frac 23,\frac 23,\frac 23)$

From this it is simple enough to find the height and length of an edge.
The corresponding vertex opposite the origin $(\frac 43,\frac 43,\frac 43)$

Edge length: $\sqrt 2$
Height: $\frac {2}{\sqrt 3}$
And the distance between the two opposite vertices: $\frac {4}{\sqrt 3}$

We can scale all of this by $\frac {s}{\sqrt 2}$ to suit a different edge length.